# Django template: check for empty query set

Tags: django, django-templates

Is there a way to check for an empty query set in the Django template? In the example below, I only want the NOTES header to be displayed if there are notes.

If I put an {% empty %} inside the "for" then it does display whatever is inside the empty tag, so it knows it's empty.

I'm hoping for something that does not involve running the query twice.

```
{% if notes - want something here that works %}
     NOTES:
     {% for note in notes %}
         {{note.text}}  
     {% endfor  %}
{% endif  %}
```

Clarification: the above example "if notes" does not work - it still displays the header even with an empty query set.

Here's a simplified version of the view

```
sql = "select * from app_notes, app_trips where"
notes = trip_notes.objects.raw(sql,(user_id,))

return render_to_response(template, {"notes":notes},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Edit: the view select selects from multiple tables.

Comment: Are you sure it runs the query twice? And, an easy suggestion would be "caching", but it doesn't answer your question.

Comment: My issue is not that it runs the query twice. My example doesn't work.  It shows the header even though the query set is empty.

Comment: post your view please

Comment: Why `{% if notes %}` does not work ?

Comment: Should it? I hoped it would, but it doesn't. I use the "if" for single variables, but it never works (for me, anyway) for query results.

Comment: `notes` is a raw query set, which unlike regular query sets doesn't define a `__nonzero__` method.  So they evaluate to True even when empty.  http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__

Answer (score 51):

Have a look at the **{% empty %}** tag.
Example from the documentation

```
<ul>
{% for athlete in athlete_list %}
    <li>{{ athlete.name }}</li>
{% empty %}
    <li>Sorry, no athletes in this list.</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty

If you are interested in a table, or some kind of heading if there are results, add the `forloop.first`:

  {% for athlete in athlete_list %}
  {% if forloop.first %}
  Athlete Name:
  {% endif %}
- {{ athlete.name }}
  {% empty %}
- Sorry, no athletes in this list.
  {% endfor %}

Comment: While very useful, it does not actually answer the question. `empty` will run once when there are no elements. In the question, the OP wishes to display a text when there *are* elements in the list. (But only once)

Comment: @T'n'E look at my updated, which includes the lists

Answer (score 39):

Try `{% if notes.all %}`. It works for me.

Comment: Works for me too, and I prefer this to `.count`, as that would issue a `select count(*)` query whereas I think this will cache the queryset if there is one.

Comment: Do not use queryset as a boolean value: instead of `if queryset:` use `if queryset.exists():` Remember, that querysets are lazy, and if you use queryset as a boolean value, an inappropriate query to a database will be carried out.
@Chris approach is better

Comment: Thanks for the solution @KishorPawar, though in the template it doesn't have the parentheses: `if queryset.exists`.

Comment: @KishorPawar It's fine to use `if queryset: ` because the QuerySet class overrides the `__bool__` magic method. See https://github.com/django/django/blob/ca9872905559026af82000e46cde6f7dedc897b6/django/db/models/query.py#L283.

Comment: Yes, it is @RuneKaagaard . Though the document says to use `exists()`. 
See the explanation for `bool()`. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated

Answer (score 8):

It's unfortunate that you're stuck using a raw query set - they're missing a lot of useful behavior.

You could convert the raw query set into a list in the view:

```
notes_as_list = list(notes)
return render_to_response(template, {"notes":notes_as_list},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Then check it as a boolean in the template:

```
{% if notes %}
    Header
    {% for note in notes %}
        {{ note.text }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

You could also make it happen without conversions using `forloop.first`:

```
{% for note in notes %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
         Header
    {% endif %}
    {{ note.text }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The forloop.first works for me. Nice hack. The other one doesn't. It lists all the letters of the query itself: R A W Q  U E R Y  S E L E

Comment: Yeah, I checked the source for `make_list` but overlooked that it's registered as a `stringfilter`, which means it converts the argument to a unicode object if it isn't already.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 6):

In your view check whether `notes` is empty or not. If it is then you pass `None` instead:

```
{"notes": None}
```

In your template you use `{% if notes %}` as normal.

Comment: This would require running it twice, no?

Comment: what? why? you should just assign your query to a variable `notes` and then do something like `{"notes": notes if len(notes) else None}` and you can then check if notes is None in your templates like Simeon suggests. This is the proper way to do this.

Comment: I think its better to do ``notes.count()`` - last I checked ``len(notes)`` pulls every record from the database whereas count simply issues a count query.

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
{% if notes != None %}
    {% if notes %}
        NOTES:
        {% for note in notes %}
            {{ note.text }}  
        {% endfor  %}
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    NO NOTES AT ALL
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Nope. It still prints the header (but no notes)

Answer (score 3):

Your original solution

```
{% if notes %}
    Header
    {% for note in notes %}
        {{ note.text }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Works now with Django 1.7 and thanks to QuerySet caching, it does not cost and extra query.

Answer (score 3):

Often the right way to do this is to use the `{% with ... %}` tag. This caches the query so it runs only once and also gives you more flexibility with your markup than using `{% empty %}`.

```html
{% with notes as my_notes %}
{% if my_notes %}
<ul>
  {% for note in my_notes %}
  <li>{{ note }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<p>Sorry, no notes available</p>
{% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

With this particular example I'm not sure how useful it is but if you're querying Many-to-Many field, for instance, it's likely what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

### Use {% empty %} in django templates

```
{% if list_data %}
    {% for data in list_data %}
        {{ data.field_1 }}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>No data found!</p>
{% endif %}
```

**We can write above code with {% empty %}.**

```
{% for data in list_data %}
    {{ data.field_1 }}
{% empty %}
    <p>No data found!</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `{% empty %}` for a "for loop" as in:

```
{% for object in list %}
<p>{{ object }}</p>
{% empty %}
<p>list is empty</p>
{% endfor %}
```

use '.all'

```
{% if object.something.all %}
```